# How do I keep WP db content synchronized in the filesystem?

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for an easy way to sync content that is in the Wordpress DB with the file system. Pages and Posts mostly, but any additional content would be great. I'm not looking to cover 100% of the DB content, just the most used configurations.

This is the Wordpress workflow I'm looking for:

1. Create a file in the filesystem, ie. `/repo/posts/mypost.yml`
2. Run a Wordpress command-line, ie. `wp sync`, which checks for sync status between my filesystem `/repo/` and the content in the database.
3. Differing content from the db is exported and from the filesystem imported.
4. In case of conflict (double changes in both), ask for merge or whatever.

This is very common with the newer, file-based, CMSs, like Grav, Kirby, Jekyll, etc. but unfortunately, for many reasons, we're stuck with Wordpress.

That way we can use git and edit and version content in a much more robust way.

Comment: You want to version control wp page post content in git?

Comment: Yes, I do. Once they are files, the team can use git to version, branch, merge, etc. So the idea is that the files be in a readable format, ie. YAML.

Comment: Yes, Git is more utilised way of implementation. I think you have to specify your question

Comment: but how do I dump the database into files so that I can use git?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress already has built-in version control in the database, called [revisions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Revisions). If you use different user accounts, WordPress will even lock pages that are being edited, preventing collisions.

Additionally, you can export the database to an .sql file and store it in your custom theme directory which you should manage with git. You only need to version control your custom theme directory, because all non-custom WordPress files already [have version control](https://wordpress.org/download/source/). However, you can export the database every now and then to keep your git repository complete. Additionally you should ask your hosting provider to create daily backups.

This will give you full version control on everything (git for the theme and WordPress for the content). Developers will be able to take the git repository and rebuild the installation locally, to change the theme. Content can be edited remote in WP, with WP versioning and daily back-ups for security reasons.

Note that exporting your database to an sql file can be done by using a database manager like [PHPmyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net) or [Adminer](http://adminer.org) and using the export functionality or by using [a WordPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/backupwordpress/).